# Express root get route overriding other routes

Tags: node.js, express

I'm in the process of building a React.js project that uses Express to handle all my backend configuration. I have a main routes file that has all my routes inside of it.

```
// Root Routes
app.get('*', mainRoutes.Root);

// Taxonomy Routes
app.post('/api/v1/taxonomy/create', taxonomyRoutes.Create);
app.get('/api/v1/taxonomy/get', taxonomyRoutes.GetAll);
```

I'm serving the index.html page on every route, then letting my react router handle the front end based on the route.

```
class MainRoutes {
  constructor() {
    // Main root file to serve.
    this.rootFile = 'index.html';
    // Bind methods.
    this.Root = this.Root.bind(this);
  }

  /**
   * Root, index route function for application.
   * @param {Object} req
   * @param {Object} res
   */
  Root(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(this.rootFile));
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `*` get route, overrides any other get route.

```
app.get('*', mainRoutes.Root);
```

So when the route `/api/v1/taxonomy/get` gets hit, the below route doesn't actually fire.

```
app.get('/api/v1/taxonomy/get', taxonomyRoutes.GetAll);
```

How can I have them both work? While still using `get`.

Comment: Just change the order and put your catch-all route last. If a route doesn't match express just moves on and checks the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `*` matches everything include your taxonomy routes and it is the first route. Just update the order when you define your routes

```
// Taxonomy Routes
app.post('/api/v1/taxonomy/create', taxonomyRoutes.Create);
app.get('/api/v1/taxonomy/get', taxonomyRoutes.GetAll);

// Root Routes
app.get('*', mainRoutes.Root);
```